# How to combine user input with list of tuples and write the complete list of tuples to the file?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to take user input and convert it in the form of a list of tuples. 
What I want to do is that, I need to take the data from the user and convert it in the form of
`[(Code,Name, Price)]` and finally combine this user input with the previous list and write the new list to the same file.

The problem I am facing is that as soon as the program completes taking user input, WinHugs is showing an error like this `Program error: Prelude.read: no parse`.

Here is the code:

```
type Code=Int
type Price=Int
type Name=String
type ProductDatabase=(Code,Name,Price)

finaliser=do
           a<-input_taker 
           b<-list_returner
           let w=a++b
           outh <- openFile "testx.txt" WriteMode
           Print outh w
           Close outh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using lazy IO to read from a file while you're writing to it at the same time. This causes problems when `read` sees data that has been partially written.

We need to force the reading of the input data to be complete before you try writing to the file. One way of doing this is to use `seq` to force the list of products to be read into memory.

```
list_returner :: IO ([ProductDatabase])
list_returner = do
    inh <- openFile "testx.txt" ReadMode
    product_text <- hGetContents inh
    let product :: [ProductDatabase]
        product = read product_text
    product `seq` hClose inh
    return product
```

Also, this will fail if the file is empty. The file should contain at least `[]` before running your code the first time, so that it will parse as the empty list.

Comment: :I am getting the error "Can't find imported module "Control.DeepSeq""

Comment: @Roy: It's in [the deepseq package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.2.0.1). I'm not too familiar with how to install packages on WinHugs, but I'd recommend installing [the Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) instead, as it is much more up to date and includes a number of common packages, including deepseq, out of the box.

Comment: Any other way of doing this, i mean other than deepseq

Comment: @Roy: Actually, since `read` will force the entire input, it should be enough to use `seq` instead of `deepseq`. Try that.

Comment: :Tried. But Same Error "Program error: Prelude.read: no parse"

Comment: @Roy: Is there anything in the file to begin with? There has to be at least `[]` in the file before running this the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me, except for certain style points.  It should work like that.  Try to separate concerns more.  The exception "no parse" means that the `read` function was unable to convert its argument string to the desired type.  The base library coming with Hugs may be more restrictive on spaces and line feeds.  I would recommend using GHC instead of Hugs in general.

In case you're interested:  One style point you may want to consider is using `withFile` instead of an `openFile`/`hClose` combination.  You may also want to use the `writeFile` with `show`:

```
writeFile "testx.txt" (show w)
```

Another style point:  Your `input_taker` action should not return a list.  There is really no reason to return a list.  Return a single tuple instead, so you can use `(:)` instead of `(++)`.  In general the usage of `(++)` indicates that you may be taking the wrong approach.

Further your `ProductDatabase` type name is misleading, because I would interpret `[ProductDatabase]` as a list of databases.  Your tuple is a `Product`.

Final style point:  This is really just about code beauty, so it's controversial.  This is not C/C++, so you would really want to write `f x` instead of `f(x)`:

```
    ...
    return product

-- Since your `Product` is just a type alias, I would use
-- a smart constructor:
product :: Code -> Name -> Price -> Product
product = (,,)

readProduct :: IO Product
readProduct = do
    ...
    code <- fmap read getLine
    ...
    name <- getLine
    ...
    price <- fmap read getLine
    return (product code name price)
```